# Long SQL file runs SQL Server out of memory (22,000 lines)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, memory, out-of-memory

I have a file of a `.sql` file that is about 22,000 lines long. It's generated by something else, but basically just contains one update statement per line.

I get this error when I run the file in SQL Server Management Studio.

> There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to
>   run this query

I think I just need to split this query file up, but I'm not sure the best way to go about it. I could cut the file into 2000 line chunks or something I suppose.

This seems like a simple problem, and I will be doing this often enough I would like to come up with a good solution. Any ideas?

Comment: 22000 updates sounds like something is not being done right.  There's no way to make this a more set-based operation?

Comment: Well its created from an excel spreadsheet that a very specialized tool creates.  The spreadsheet has X lines that need to update corresponding rows in the database, but this is a very old tool and only exports to Excel.

Comment: Your life sucks.  :)  Excel is the bane of any DBA.

Comment: How about increasing the SQL server's memory?

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look into running your script via [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of going through the SSMS GUI interface.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem and running below command in command prompt from [blog](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2009/09/25/running-large-mssql-scripts-amp--resulting-memory-errors) saved me.

```
   sqlcmd -S YOURSQLSERVER\INSTANCENAME -i "C:\Your Script.sql"
```

Answer (score 3):

You're probably hitting a limit on batch size, so SQL Server is having issues parsing the batch. If you can run in about ~5000 line chunks (highlight, Execute) then that'd confirm my theory.

Once you know the correct batch size down, you can either:

1. Insert GO statements in between, to force a new batch
2. Split to multiple files

A little shell scripting should suffice for either. The [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) of [split](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split), [head](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?head), and [tail](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tail) should prove useful.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when running on SQL Management studio, what I did was execute it in command line osql –S localhost –d mydb –E –i .\hugescript.sql

http://tutewall.com/cannot-execute-script-insufficient-memory-error-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate more memory to your server, with this solution:

1. In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select Properties.
2. Click the Memory node.
3. Under Server Memory Options, enter the amount that you want for
   Minimum server memory and Maximum server memory.

default of maximum is 2147483647 , I change it to 9147483647 and my problem was solved.